# shellscript is having trouble finding a file

Tags: shell-script

I have a shellscript that is having trouble finding a file. The text file exists so I don't understand what the issue is.

```
#!/bin/ksh
goodmain $1 | sed -e '1,/mmxxaa/d'

$ ls -l
total 1364
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 s student  94563 Apr 23 23:55 a.out
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 s student     19 Apr 28 17:13 boo
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student     89 Apr 24 00:58 cookies
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student   1622 Dec  6 23:49 doc
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student    148 Apr 23 16:14 textfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student 597061 Apr 23 23:56 fn
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 s student  94563 Apr 28 16:56 goodmain
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student 427993 Apr 23 23:47 main.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student 145256 Apr 24 00:40 main.o
-rw-r--r--. 1 s student     72 Apr 28 16:53 makefile
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 s student     46 Apr 28 17:24 p4
$ ./p4 textfile
./p4: line 2: goodmain: not found
```

Comment: What about ./goodmain ? (adding "./" before the name of the file)

Comment: @gapz thank you :). Didn't think that was necessary in a shellscript.

Answer (score 1):

Since the current path is not in the **PATH** variable, you have to specify completely the location of the file: you can add "./" if your file is in the same location as the script or you can give the full path:

```
./goodmain
```

Or:

```
/full/path/goodmain
```